# How to Start FFMpeg Screen Recording with Custom Shortcut

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, ffmpeg

What is the easiest way to run a FFMpeg screen recording command with a custom keyboard shortcut? Adding my raw ffmpeg command to a Custom Shortcut in the Keyboard settings doesn't do the trick.

Here's the command I'm using:

```bsh
ffmpeg -f x11grab  -s 1366x768 -i :0.0 -r 25 -vcodec libx264 `date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`_BTEVCpcampFormBook.mkv
```

The command works fine in terminal. It runs until you terminate it and outputs the file as expected, and running it as a keystroke doesn't appear to do anything, at least visibly. Also, running

```bsh
gnome-terminal -e "ffmpeg -f x11grab  -s 1366x768 -i :0.0 -r 25 -vcodec libx264 `date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`_BTEVCpcampFormBook.mkv"
```

does open up a terminal window and run a function for a split second, but then the window closes again immediately. Adding "; bash" to the end of the string doesn't keep the window open. Managed to get a screenshot of the terminal window right before it closes, it seems to be terminating mid-execution of the function without displaying any errors. Here that is:

[image: ffmpeg terminal window before termination]

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Hi dessert, thanks for the reply. Edited question accordingly.

Comment: Updated with release description.

Comment: Don't know anything about the shortcut component of the question, but `ffmpeg -f x11grab  -s 1366x768 -i :0.0 -r 25` should be `ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1366x768 -framerate 25 -i :0.0`. More info: [x11grab docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#x11grab).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Running the command with "-x sh -c" as opposed to "-e" executes the function without exiting the window. Syntax borrowed from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/198015/open-gnome-terminal-programmatically-and-execute-commands-after-bashrc-was-execu) superuser discussion.

The full function:

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'ffmpeg -f x11grab  -s 1366x768 -i :0.0 -r 25 -vcodec libx264 `date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`_BTEVCpcampFormBook.mkv; exec bash'
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment your `-r` is incorrect. By coincidence it won't make a difference as is since 25 is the default for x11grab, but if you change it to any other value it will have to perform a frame rate conversion from 25 to your `-r` value. To prevent that remove `-r` and replace it with `-framerate`, and move it so it is an input option (before the `-i`).